# how to use array_push()

Tags: php, arrays

I want to push new data in array which each value of them.

```
$array = array("menu1" => "101", "menu2" => "201"); 
array_push($array, "menu3" => "301");
```

But I got an error syntax.

And if I use like this :

```
$array = array("menu1" => "101", "menu2" => "201"); 
array_push($array, "menu3", "301");

result is : Array ( [menu1]=>101  [menu2]=>201   [0]=>menu3  [1]=>301 )

My hope the result is : Array ( [menu1]=>101  [menu2]=>201   [menu3]=>301 )
```

I want push new [menu3]=>'301' but I dont know how. Please help me, the answer will be appreciate

Comment: [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) doesn't provide the functionality you want. But there are other ways to work with arrays. Have you read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying)?

Comment: use array_merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$array["menu3"] = "301"
```

as for array_push

> array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array

so for associative arrays is a no match

another suitable function for what you want but it requires an array argument is `array_merge`

```
$result = array_merge(array("one" => "1"), array("two" => "2"));
```